# How to use formik with Antd Design Form?

Tags: reactjs, antd, formik

I am trying to implement formik validation with Ant design form, formik is able to capture the input/selected data but when I click onSubmit, it doesn't print anything in console.

```
export default function SearchForm() {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      city: "",
      checkIn: "",
    },
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      console.log(values)
    },
  });

  //console.log(formik.values)

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
      <FormLabel>Select City</FormLabel>
      <Form.Item>
        <Select
          name="city"
          value={formik.values.city}
          placeholder="Please select a country"
          onChange={(value) => formik.setFieldValue("city", value)}
        >
          <Select.Option value="mumbai">Mumbai</Select.Option>
          <Select.Option value="bengaluru">Bengaluru</Select.Option>
          <Select.Option value="delhi">Delhi</Select.Option>
          <Select.Option value="hyderabad">Hyderabad</Select.Option>
          <Select.Option value="chennai">Chennai</Select.Option>
        </Select>
      </Form.Item>
      <FormLabel>Check-In-Date</FormLabel>
       <Form.Item>
         <DatePicker
           name="checkIn"
           value={formik.values.checkIn}
           format={dateFormat}
           onChange={(value) => formik.setFieldValue("checkIn", value)}
           />
       </Form.Item>
      <SubmitButton htmlType="submit">Book Now</SubmitButton>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

And by giving values, the placeholder text is not visible, and also in DatePicker, it is saving as Moment Object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally, I got an answer!! When we use the Ant design form, it works a little different from the normal form, instead of using `onSubmit` we have to use `onFinish` and generally you pass `value` and function to capture `event.target.value` in normal form but in Ant design form we have to pass `onChange={(value) => formik.setFieldValue("checkIn", value)}` and it will simply capture the change.

```
<Form onFinish={formik.handleSubmit}>
      <FormLabel>Select City</FormLabel>
      <Form.Item>
        <Select
          name="city"
          placeholder="Please select a country"
          onChange={(value) => formik.setFieldValue("city", value)}
        >
          <Select.Option value="mumbai">Mumbai</Select.Option>
          <Select.Option value="bengaluru">Bengaluru</Select.Option>
          <Select.Option value="delhi">Delhi</Select.Option>
          <Select.Option value="hyderabad">Hyderabad</Select.Option>
          <Select.Option value="chennai">Chennai</Select.Option>
        </Select>
      </Form.Item>
      <FormLabel>Check-In-Date</FormLabel>
       <Form.Item>
         <DatePicker
           name="checkIn"
           format={dateFormat}
           onChange={(value) => formik.setFieldValue("checkIn", value)}
           />
      </Form.Item>
      <SubmitButton htmlType="submit">Book Now</SubmitButton>
    </Form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `Validation Schema` in `useFormik` and import `Yup`, like this :

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';

const FormSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    title: Yup.string().required('Please enter notification title')
});

<Formik
    validationSchema={FormSchema}>
        <Form>
            <div className='grid-row'>
                <div className='grid-1'>
                    <Field name='title' required={true} label='Title'component={Input} />
                </div>
        </Form>
</Formik>
```

Comment: I and understand that but the first part I want to just console when submit it